# What kind of persistent data does Kibana stores in path.data?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

There is a Kibana configuration called [`path.data`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html) that says:

> The path where Kibana stores persistent data not saved in Elasticsearch.

What kind of persistent data is stored there?

As far as I am aware, Kibana stores most of its information in Elasticsearch under its index (`.kibana` by default).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much documentation on this, however I could find a Elasticsearch team member response to another [question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-keep-state-dashboards-visualizations-settings-on-docker-elk/94302). Stating:

> You're correct that all Kibana saved objects are stored in Elasticsearch, in the .kibana index. It doesn't write anything to the filesystem (save for maybe some temporary files, but even that I'm pretty sure doesn't happen).

Therefore, I would say that only temporary information is stored in the `path.data` and all the relevant information (for either persistence or for monitorization) is stored under the `.kibana` index.

Can someone else confirm this?